# R how to restore name references after converting vectors to numbers

Tags: r, data-conversion

Following the question here I managed to easily convert vectors to numbers. I'm faced now with two problems.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
v1 <- rep(c('a','b'),3)
v2 <- rep(c('c','d','e'),2)
vdf <- data.frame(v1, v2)
vdf[] <- lapply(vdf, as.integer)
```

The data that I have now in vdf is as follows:

```
  v1 v2
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  1  3
4  2  1
5  1  2
6  2  3
```

After processing the data I plot the v1 & v2 and I get something like:

```
barplot(sort(table(vdf$v1)))
barplot(sort(table(vdf$v2)))
```

[image: RPlotDual]

Of course, the numbers 1,2 & 1,2,3 are now meaningless and I need to show back the reference values (a,b & c,d,e)

Any ideas as to how can I conversion back to the reference values I have?

Comment: Have you considered using factors? Why are you converting to itnegers in the first place?

Comment: You could just do `barplot(sort(table(vdf$v1)))` as `table` gets the frequency of character/factor/numeric elements and then you can do the `barplot` without the conversion.  If we really need this conversion, then create a copy of the `vdf` and assign the output of `lapply` to that

Comment: Heroka, I need to use integers as I need this values for other calculations. Akrun, I understand on making a copy of vdf, but I don't see how I can reassign with lapply. I don't know what numbers have been assigned to the numbers

Answer (score 1):

to convert letters to numbers, it would be probably better to use `match`, such as in:

```
v1 <- match(rep(c('a','b'),3),letters)
v2 <- match(rep(c('c','d','e'),2),letters)
vdf <- data.frame(v1, v2)
vdf

> vdf
  v1 v2
1  1  3
2  2  4
3  1  5
4  2  3
5  1  4
6  2  5
```

this way you get a -> 1; b -> 2, c -> 3, etcetera.
I don't recall the function for "going back", but it should be easy to find (difficult to understand, however, why you would need integer values in the first place, though... a factor seems more useful, here, since the fact that a = 1 and d = 4 is purely coincidental)

Comment: I need to convert it to numbers for to work on prediction algorithms, but on the outputs I need to know what each number represents. What you presented thought is how to convert it to numbers, which I get form vdf[] <- lapply(vdf, as.integer) and it converts all the dataframe. What I've presented is an example, but there are multiple columns and factors for some of the columns in the original case

Comment: mmm. I fear I misinterpreted... so you are not interested in "letters", but just want to convert a "categorical" variable to a integer representation ? In that case, applying "as.numeric" on  a factor variable should do the trick, and later on you can "go back" using the "levels order" of the original factor.

Comment: Also (I may be mistaken, here, since I don't know what algorithms you are talking about), but it seems to me that treating a categorical variable (even if it is "ordinal") as a continuous numerical one could be dangerous.

Comment: I figured out that for this example I can put back the reference values with: vdf$v1<-factor(vdf$v1, levels=c(1,2), labels=c('a', 'b')). But in some cases I don't see clearly what number has been assigned to the original reference value, like is it the case that 1=a & 2=b or 1=b & 2=a?

Comment: when you "build" a factor, I think levels are assigned according to alphabetical order of the labels, unless you reassign them, so for example:  aa = 1, ab = 2, b = 3, etcetera.

Comment: `levels(vdf$v1)` will give you an array of strings ordered according to the assignment in the array. so in the factor, the first element of `levels(vdf$v1)` has "value" 1, etcetera

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out based on the comments. Here is the code if it helps anyone:

```
v1 <- rep(c('a','b'),3)
v2 <- rep(c('c','d','e'),2)
vdf <- data.frame(v1, v2)
LeV1 <- levels(vdf$v1)
LeV2 <- levels(vdf$v2)    
vdf[] <- lapply(vdf, as.integer)
vdf$v1<-factor(vdf$v1, levels=unique(vdf$v1), labels=LeV1)
vdf$v2<-factor(vdf$v2, levels=unique(vdf$v2), labels=LeV2)
```